# How to avoid getting locked out of your GIT repo / SSH?

Tags: git, version-control, ssh

I created ssh keys using ssh-keygen and then created a repo on a source code repo site, assembla.com as a GIT repository. I had to upload the file with my private key (or was it my public key?) to the repo and now I am able to clone no problem.

I had a friend try and access the repo and he wasn't able to, which is good because I had not configured any guests to the repo and wanted it to be private.

But now I am unsure about how to ensure that I do not lose access to my own repo in the future. Do I need to keep a copy of my .ssh folder from my user dir? Export keychains from the keychain tool in mac os x? I'm still trying to get a full understanding of how this works but doesn't SVN simply need username+pass for repo access? What should I do so I can confidently and safely use a GIT SSH repo such that I won't lose access to it in future?

Comment: If you had to upload your private key, then you've been deceived. Never give away your private key, it's private.

Comment: Detail: You didn't upload a key to the *repository*, you uploaded it to the hosting servers. SSH access to repositories works by connecting to the *server* via SSH, which then gives you some restricted shell access making it possible to get to the repo. It's the SSH server that handles authentication, not Git, so this is really just about SSH authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three files in your .ssh folder:

- `known_hosts` is just a list of hosts you've connected to. Its primary purpose is protecting you from man-in-the-middle attacks, where someone evil pretends to be the host you try to connect to. You might as well include it in your backups, but it won't make you lose access.
- `id_rsa` is the private key. This is what you use to identify yourself. As the name says, it's private. Anyone who has it is, as far as this keypair is concerned, you. You should certainly back it up - but safely!
- `id_rsa.pub` is the public key. This is what you actually give people. When you ssh somewhere using keypair authentication, it's the combination of the public key on the server and the private key from your client that authenticates you. Back it up too; without it, everything you're currently doing will keep working, but you wouldn't be able to pass it out to any more servers, so you'd be kinda stuck.

As for empty passphrases, well, a lot of people do that. It's certainly not the most secure, but there are worse sins to commit. The passphrase is just an extra layer of protection. To be identified as you, you have to provide the private key (something you own) and the passphrase (something you know). In terms of avoiding getting locked out of an account, well, don't forget it and you won't have problems. An empty one gives you increased convenience, and no danger of forgetting it, at the cost of some security.

Finally, most git hosting doesn't use ssh access exclusively. If you have an account with assembla that can be authenticated some other way, then you might have the ability to come back and add or swap out keypairs.

Answer (score 2):

You should keep your private ssh key in dry, warm, sunless, secure place: your HDD, your backup HDD, your backup place in some other city/country.

Since your key protected with strong long fat random secure password, you can save it "as is", but better to keep it private.

Comment: Thank you! My .ssh folder contains 3 files: known_hosts, id_rsa, id_rsa.pub. I suppose I keep them all right? And a restoration (say on a wiped machine) would simply be to recreate the .ssh dir structure with the files? when I generated I used an empty passphrase. Is that a problem?

Comment: Yes, you keep all three files.  Having no passphrase on your public key means that if anyone ever gets their hands on your private key, they will have open access to all the hosts you use that key on.  So it's best to set one and make it a strong passphrase, not easily guessed.  You can add a passphrase to your private key with the ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -p command.

Comment: You should save only id_rsa -- only it contains private key.
*.pub file can be generated from id_rsa with "ssh-keyget -y -f id_rsa >id_rsa.pub" command.
you can use non-protected key on your machine, if you want, just be sure no one have access to it.
you can set password for your key by running "ssh-keygen -p -f id_rsa". It will overwrite your key with password-protected one, backup it after.

Comment: Is there some reason *not* to back up your public key? You're kind of defeating the point of backups if you have to do post-processing to get things to actually work right.